# Unable to fetch the Get-AzDiagnosticSetting via powershell in Azure FrontDoor WAF Policy. Is this allows us to fetch the diagnostic settings?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-waf

Get-AzDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid
status code 'BadRequest'
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.DiagnosticSettingsOperations.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.DiagnosticSettingsOperationsExtensions.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.DiagnosticSettingsOperationsExtensions.List(IDiagnosticSettingsOperations operations, String resourceUri)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Diagnostics.GetAzureRmDiagnosticSettingCommand.ProcessRecordInternal()
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.MonitorCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet(), Code: Null, Status code:Null, Reason phrase: Null
At C:\Users\n1542975\Desktop\MigrationScripts\WAF_Policy.ps1:121 char:26

- ... gsettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceID $FrontDoorWAFPolicyNa ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzDiagnosticSetting], PSInvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Diagnostics.GetAzureRmDiagnosticSettingCommand

Answer (score 0):

Yes using 'Get-AzDiagnosticSetting' cmdlet you can fetch the diagnostic setting of a particular resource.
We have Ran the below commands to fetch the diagnostics settings for the front door using remote PowerShell & from Azure CLI.
AzureCLI Cmdlet:

```
az monitor diagnostic-settings show --resource-group <resource-group> --resource <resource-name> --resource-type Microsoft.Network/frontdoors --name <diagnosticsettingname>
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]

Power Shell Cmdlet :

```
Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId <resourceId> -Name <diagnosticsettingName>
```

Here is the sample output for reference :

[image]

You can refer the below Azure documentation for more information about the syntaxes for [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-6.3.0) & [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/diagnostic-settings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_diagnostic_settings_show).

Comment: Encouraged by your post, I tried `Get-AzDiagnosticSetting`  and `Set-AzDiagnosticSetting` on an Azure Automation account. Tried the CLI too. But, neither worked. MS has accepted this to be a bug.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/18334